# Multiple WHERE clauses in DB::RAW in Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have a query as shown below.

I would want to introduce or select data as `DB::raw('select SUM(review_details.param_value) / COUNT(review_headers.id) AS avgUserReview')` and apply some WHERE clauses to this query alone.

```
$data = BusinessDetail::select(
    'business_details.id as businessId',  
    'business_details.name as description', 
    'cities.description as city',
    'countries.description as country',
    'sectors.description as sector'
)->join('sectors', 'business_details.sector_id', '=', 'sectors.id')
->join('countries', 'business_details.country_id', '=', 'countries.id')
->join('cities', 'business_details.city_id', '=', 'cities.id')
->leftJoin('review_headers', 'business_details.id', '=', 'review_headers.business_detail_id')
->leftJoin('review_details', 'review_headers.id', '=', 'review_details.review_header_id')
->leftJoin('rate_params', 'review_details.rate_param_id', '=', 'rate_params.id')
->leftJoin('param_types', 'rate_params.param_type_id', '=', 'param_types.id')
->groupBy('business_details.id');
```

I would want to introduce another SELECT statement as below and apply the WHERE clauses to only that STATEMENT

`DB::raw('select SUM(review_details.param_value) / COUNT(review_headers.id) AS avgUserReview')`

There WHERE clauses are

```
->where('review_details.param_value', '<>', NULL)
->where('review_details.param_value', '<>', '')
->whereIn('rate_param_id', [1, 3, 4, 5])
->where('review_headers.review_status', '=', 1)
```

I mean something like `DB::raw('select SUM(review_details.param_value) / COUNT(review_headers.id) AS avgUserReview from review_details where conditions')`

I have tried `DB::raw('select SUM(review_details.param_value) / COUNT(review_headers.id) AS avgUserReview from review_details where review_headers.review_status = 1')` but getting `Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'select SUM(review_details.param_value) / COUNT(review_headers.id) AS avgUserRevi'`

Comment: what do you want to do ?

Comment: @RiponUddin `select SUM(review_details.param_value) / COUNT(review_headers.id) AS avgUserReview from review_details where conditions`

Comment: I don't think you can chain a `DB::raw()` like that. You could try chaining from the `ReviewDetail` model with the `selectRaw('SUM(review_details.param_value) / COUNT(review_headers.id) AS avgUserReview')` function

Comment: @RobBiermann sorry I am lost.  How do  I do that?

Comment: It's not related with Laravel Raw, it's your SQL query syntax error, paste your SQL code in SQL database management, eg: phpmyadmin and run to check is this SQL is correct, based on your SQL query, I can see that review_headers is not linked, perhaps left join?

Comment: @Momo  it's there `->leftJoin('review_headers', 'business_details.id', '=', 'review_headers.business_detail_id')`